# Clickhouse group by projection or materialized view

Tags: database, clickhouse, materialized-views

Suppose we have a table "statements" (with 100 milions rows) with these columns

(country, store, user, amount, year)

We need to find the top 5 stores by total amount.

The following SQL query will achieve this:

```
select sum(amount) s, store
from statements
group by store
order by s
limit 5
```

A materialized view or projection could help with performance.

However, if the GROUP BY clause could be filtered by user, year, or country, the SUM function would have to work with different grouped rows for each store.

What can we do to speed up the query?

One solution could be to create a projection with multiple GROUP BY clauses. However, if the filterable columns are the majority of the projection table target, the projection table would be larger and performance would be lost.

Comment: That query should run pretty fast no matter how you group it. I would try a PROJECTION and see what the improvement is. Let me know if you need help defining it.

Comment: The problem is not group by clause, but the where clause before.

select sum(amount) s, store
from statements
where (some filter on statements)
group by store
order by s
limit 5

Infact these "wheres" change the next group by results
(i.e. where country = IT and user = Mike, or user = John and store  = B)

What projection could be use?